# Logout error when passing user object through handlebars partial

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, templating, express-handlebars

So I'm trying to render the user's name on the navbar. So far I have a routes folder, views folder and a partial folder. When I try to render the user's name on the profile page and the homepage it works.

This is it:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Site',
    name: req.user.username, // <-- Line 10
    image: req.user.image,
  });
});

// @desc     Profile
// @route    GET/profile
router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  res.render('profile', {
    name: req.user.username,
    title: req.user.username,
    image: req.user.image,
  });
});
```

However, when I go to /logout, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Desktop\Code\site\routes\index.js:10:20
```

if I remove line 10 and 11 and I try to log out it works fine. I though this may be a problem because _nav is a partial but then why am I getting an error only when I use it on '/'.

Thanks!

Comment: Your error is saying the `req.user` is undefined, which means that `user` is not a property on the request object `req`. You need to ensure that this property is being added with the correct value

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question i'm new to express. If req.user is undefined then why does it show the user image and name and only show that error when I logout?

Comment: It's hard to tell why it might be defined at one point but not at another point without seeing more of your code. Are you using passport JS for authentication?

Comment: Yes I'm using local, google and twitter. What code would you need?

Comment: perhaps the parts which involve passport. I’m not that familiar with passport so I’m not too sure what your issue might be

Comment: I posted a thread on the node subreddit, hopefully they will be able to help. Thanks for trying to solve my problem btw.